# Create Microsoft Graph Api Subscription for accept/reject meeting event by attendees

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar, microsoft-graph-webhooks

In my project, I have created Rest API project to create subscription and to listen notification from Microsoft Graph API.
I want subscription for following things:

1. When I create meeting room event then I want to get notification if any attendees accept/reject that meeting room event.
2. If whole meeting event is cancelled or moves to another time slot or added any new attendees.

I was expecting all above gets covered by following code but it is not :

```
                var subscription = new Subscription
                {
                    ChangeType = "updated,deleted",
                    NotificationUrl = $"{_notificationHost}/listen",
                    Resource = "me/events",
                    ClientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    IncludeResourceData = false,
                    // Subscription only lasts for one hour
                    ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
                };

It does not send notification when accept or reject done by attendee with 'Do not send a response'. How I can get notification for this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed both scenarios :

1. I am getting notification for attendees's reject/approve response on my listen api : NotificationUrl = $"{_notificationHost}/listen",
2. If new attendess added/removed or meeting time change or meeting cancelled then also we can get notification in Listen api.

Comment: What did you do to solve the issue?

Comment: Would also like to know how this was resolved please.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not generate subscription updates when a user accepts/declines/maybe a calendar event that exists in a user's secondary calendar i.e. the calendar is not identified by `/me/calendar`.

If you set up the subscription for the primary calendar (`/me/calendar`), you will get updates via your subscription endpoint.